# node.js - Unhandled 'error' event error

Tags: gulp

Can anyone help with this error please? I have tried a few things but still learning.

```
[17:33:31] Using gulpfile ~/projects/website/gulpfile.js
[17:33:31] Starting 'default'...
[17:33:31] Starting 'clean'...
[17:33:31] Finished 'clean' after 12 ms
[17:33:31] Starting 'lint'...
[17:33:31] Finished 'lint' after 287 ms
[17:33:31] Starting 'jekyll'...
[17:33:31] Starting 'scripts'...
[17:33:31] Starting 'libs'...
[17:33:31] Starting 'html'...
[17:33:31] Starting 'images'...
[17:33:31] Starting 'fonts'...
/Users/richard/projects/website/public/../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/*
events.js:141
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: spawn jekyll ENOENT
at exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
at doNTCallback2 (node.js:429:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:343:17)`
```